# slideup a div when mouseover and hide when mouseout, but with some rules

Tags: jquery, css, mouseevent

i have 1 div called #init_ind and another div called #footer_init_ind inside of it.
the css code of #footer_init_ind marks that visible:none;
i have one function called showfooter :

```
    function showfoot( itemImg ) {

        if ($(itemImg).is(":hidden")) {
            $(itemImg).slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            $(itemImg).hide();
        }
};
```

also I have some events for slide #footer_init_ind when the mouse enter or leave that.

```
$('#init_ind').mouseenter(function(){
        showfoot('#pie_init_ind');
});

$('#init_ind').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#pie_init_ind').css("height","17px");
        $('#pie_init_ind').hide();
    });

$('#pie_init_ind').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.pie_init_txt').css("cursor", "default");
        $('#pie_init_ind').css("height","50px");
    });
    $('#pie_init_ind').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.pie_init_txt').css("cursor", "default");
        $('#pie_init_ind').css("height","17px");
        $('#pie_init_ind').hide();
    });
```

my problem is when the mouse enter #pie_init_ind and leave this for entering again in #init_ind , #pie_init_ind don't reduce his size to 17px as i want. but it works when the mouse leave #pie_init_ind for entering in another div outside #init_ind.

HOW CAN I DO THIS PLEASE????
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure because I can't see the HTML that defines these divs, but if some of your divs are nested you would see the problem you describe. For example...

```
<div a>
    <div b></div>
</div>
<div c></div>
```

If hovering over div b should increase the height of div c but hovering over div a should reduce the height of div c - by default hovering over b will trigger both events for a and b (i.e. reduce and increase the size of div c).

If you provide a link to the page in question I'll take a look at the markup. Sometimes these problems simply need a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Currently looking at the code. Not relevant to the problem at hand, but the tweet script isn't being found because the path is from root instead of local. The leading / needs to be removed from /tweet/jquery.tweet.js. Will come back to you shortly

Comment: I can't find the jQuery that calls showfoot(itemImg) and/or shortfoot(itemImg). Where is this code found? I suspect the outer <div init_ind> is interfering as follows: 1) Mouse leaves pie_init_ind and reduces size of lower div (shortfoot()). 2) Mouse enters init_ind which kicks off showfoot() and triggers the else{} condition that hides the lower div. I can't confirm this because I can't find where the 2 key functions are called as stated above.

Comment: I can see you're working on it (making changes). Do you think I'm on the right track?

Comment: function showfoot( itemImg ) {
  
  if ($(itemImg).is(":hidden")) {
   $(itemImg).slideDown("slow");
  } else {
   $(itemImg).hide();
  }
};